# How to get data in the from 'jsondata' in the desired format in angular2?

Tags: angular

The data output is an array but need to put strings like `'Month'`,`'data1%'`,
`'data2'`,`'data3'` etc at `0th position` of this.monthdata, this.data1data ... respectively.
The output getting for `this.monthdata` is

```
['Jan','feb']
```

### Required output

```
['Month','Jan','feb']    where 'Month' should come from jsondata.json
```

I have mentioned in the code.

### jsondata.json

```
[{
        "Month": "Jan",
        "data1%": "58.2",
        "data2": "90.38",
        "data3": "87.4",
        "data4": "80.85"
    },
    {
        "Month": "feb",
        "data1%": "57.2",
        "data2": "90.38",
        "data3": "57.4",
        "data4": "85.85"
    }
]
```

### service.ts

```
gethpData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('assets/json/hfollder/jsondata.json')
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    const body = res.json();
    return body || [];
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg);
    // alert('Server Error!');
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

### test.component.html

```
<button id='btn1' (click)='getdata('btn1')'>btn1</button>
<button id='btn2' (click)='getdata('btn2')'>btn2</button>
<button id='btn3' (click)='getdata('btn3')'>btn3</button>
<button id='btn4' (click)='getdata('btn4')'>btn4</button>
```

### test.component.ts

```
import { service } ....................// imported here
constructor(public jsonDataService: service){}

getdata = (id) => {
    this.jsonDataService.gethpData().subscribe(res => this.getPartOfData(id, res));
}

getPartOfData(id, res) {
    switch (id) {   
        case 'btn1':
//here getting data as ['','',''.......] where empty strings are data
//required data output as ['Month','','',''....]
            this.monthdata  = res.map(el => el.Month);
            break;          
        case 'btn2':
//here getting data as ['','',''.......] where empty strings are data
//required data output as ['data1%','','',''....]

            this.data1data  = res.map(el => el['data1%']);
            break;          
        case 'btn3':
//here getting data as ['','',''.......] where empty strings are data
//required data output as ['data2','','',''....]

            this.data2data  = res.map(el => data2: el.data2);
            break;          
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an empty array, `push` the desired first value into it, then loop over  `res.map(el => el.Month)` to `push` each element into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that simply :

```
this.monthdata  = ['Month' , ...res.map(el => el.Month) ];
```

Use ES6's array destructuring.
Follow same for others also.

Comment: 'Month' should come dynamically from jsondata.json

Comment: You are using static data then its not possible , for this you have to use mine answer from previous post.

Comment: Can you show in easy method without changing much code.

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr  Please check my updated answer on previous post, and implement that.For this one you have to do it this way. Please accept the answer and also upvote it.

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr, as you are using static el.Month, el.data2 , el['data1%'] , whats the issue with my code? , if you dont have issue with your code then mine is perfect.